# How can I copy a specific part of a URL to the clipboard with a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, string, google-chrome-extension

I have been attempting to write a chrome extension that copies a specific part of a URL when a user right clicks on a hyper link.

For instance, I am interested in copying the 17 characters that appear to the right of "Flid%3D" that appears within a URL, to the clip board.

Comment: I assume you can get the full URL at the moment?

Comment: Currently I get the full URL of the current tab, but I see that as a minor stumbling block. The manipulation of the URL is the step I have no idea of how to complete.

Comment: Since this now is a question about string manipulation, I retagged your question and updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [clipboard API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.clipboard.html) is still experimental. You can start writing your extension with it and test it if you set the experimental flag in about:flags (only possible on a dev build I think). You will have to wait to release your extension until the API is released.

> **Caution:** Don't depend on these
>   experimental APIs. They might
>   disappear, and they will change. Also,
>   the Chrome Developer Dashboard doesn't
>   allow you to upload extensions that
>   use experimental APIs.

### EDIT

So this is actually a question about string manipulation? I guess you want to use regular expressions for this, perhaps something like `/Flid%3D(.{17})/`. This searches for the first occurrence of the literal `Flid%3D` followed by the 17 characters. You would use it like this:

```
var myUrl = 'http://www.helloworld.com/Flid%3Dabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw';
var match = myUrl.match(/Flid%3D(.{17})/);
if(match !== null) {
  // we found the part
  var part = match[1];
}
```

and the resulting string in `part` would be `'abcdefghijklmnopq'`.